# Python Dictionary comprehension to copy some pairs to a new dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

While playing around with input validation, specifically checking whether the supplied data have all the required attributes specified, and discarding attributes that I don't want, I did something like this:

```
>>> input = {'v1': 'val1', 'a2':'val2', 'a3':'val3'} 
>>> print input
{'v1': 'val1', 'a3': 'val3', 'a2': 'val2'}
>>> goodkeys = ['a2', 'a3']
>>> print goodkeys
['a2', 'a3']
>>> output = {}
>>> for a in goodkeys:    
...   output[a] = input[a]
... 
>>> 
>>> print output
{'a3': 'val3', 'a2': 'val2'}
```

Which of course works.  But it occurred to me that it may be possible to do this in a more pythonic way.  I tried:

```
>>> output = {}
>>> print output
{}
>>> output = { a:v for a in goodkeys for v in input[a] }
>>> print output
{'a3': '3', 'a2': '2'}
>>>
```

Which for half a second I thought worked, then I realized that the values are wrong.  Is there a pretty Python method?  And what happened, where did Python get those values?

Comment: If `input` doesn't contain one of the good keys, say `a2` -- what do you want to happen?

Comment: Please don't use 'input' as a variable's name; it is a keyword in python 3.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [*dictionary view objects*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
goodkeys = {'a2', 'a3'}
output = {a: input[a] for a in input.viewkeys() & goodkeys}
```

where `goodkeys` is a set; [`dict.viewkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) produces a set-like object that reflects the contents of the dictionary, and `& goodkeys` produces the intersection between those keys and the `goodkeys` set. That way you only ever produce keys that are both in the input dictionary and the set of good keys.

You created a nested loop like this:

```
for a in goodkeys:
    for v in input[a]:
        # v is a single character in the string value
```

Demo:

```
>>> input = {'v1': 'val1', 'a2':'val2', 'a3':'val3'} 
>>> goodkeys = {'a2', 'a3'}
>>> {a: input[a] for a in input.viewkeys() & goodkeys}
{'a3': 'val3', 'a2': 'val2'}
```

Since `input[a]` is a string, your inner loop produced the individual characters of each value:

```
>>> for a in goodkeys:
...     for v in input[a]:
...         print a, v
... 
a3 v
a3 a
a3 l
a3 3
a2 v
a2 a
a2 l
a2 2
```

Keys must be unique, so for `a2`, one of `v`, `a`, `l` and `2` is picked with the others discarded. The dictionary comprehension sets `'a2': 'v'` first, then `'a2': 'a'`, etc. and only `'a2': '2'` remains in the output, in the end.

You didn't need to use that inner loop; you could have stuck with:

```
{a: input[v] for a in goodkeys}
```

except that if there are any keys in `goodkeys` that are not in `input` you'd get a `KeyError`. The dictionary view approach neatly sidesteps that issue.

Comment: `KeyError`s could also be avoided by simply using `{a: input[a] for a in goodkeys if a in input}` rather than using `dict.viewkeys()` and finding the intersection. One advantage being that it would work in versions of Python before 2.7, which is when `viewkeys()` was introduced.

Comment: @martineau: sure, but the OP stated they use 2.7, and the intersection operation is done *once*, in C, and is thus faster than a membership test operation each iteration.

Comment: Yes, but you edited out the fact that they were using version 2.7 from the question...so now it's more generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
output = { a:input[a] for a in goodkeys }
```

Your second `for` iterates through the characters of the string values.

Answer (score 0):

You may be over thinking this. Just try changing

```
output = { a:v for a in goodkeys for v in input[a] }
```

to simply...

```
output = { a:input[a] for a in goodkeys }
```