# Unhandled Exceptions disappear

Tags: python, exception

In [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27447789/1810447) to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447684/python-dictionary-comprehension-to-copy-some-pairs-to-a-new-dictionary)  there is a small typo.  As per the answer, I need to handle KeyError, so I tried

```
def GetInputData(inputdict, attributelist):
    result = {}
    try:
        result = {a: inputdict[v] for a in attributelist}
    except KeyError as KE:
        print "KeyError", KE
        decodeok = False
    else:
        decodeok = True
    finally:
        return decodeok, result
```

This works (after fixing the error on line 4 ... `[v]` should be `[a]`).

The Problem is that the try-except-finally causes the unhandled NameError to be hidden.  The Try breaks to the Finally section on the NameError exception and as a result decodeok doesn't get initialized.

Indeed this is due to coding errors, but I thought Exceptions not explicitly handled should still get raised?  This is causing me endless headaches!  Do I have to handle every possible exception all the time?

Comment: Perhaps you should initialize `decodeok` before your `try` block, like you do with `result`, since there is a code path through your `try` block that does not initialize it... Or you could even initialize it within the `try` block, immediately before your `result = ...` line...

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> A finally clause is always executed before leaving the try statement,
>   whether an exception has occurred or not. When an exception has
>   occurred in the try clause and has not been handled by an except
>   clause (or it has occurred in a except or else clause), it is
>   re-raised after the finally clause has been executed.

So it's not that the `NameError` isn't raised (it will be) it's that the `finally` executes before the `try:` block is left.

In any case, I'd suggest defining your function like this:

```
def get_input_data(input_dict, attributes, check=False):
    """If check is True, raises a KeyError if a key in attributes is not
    in the input dictionary."""
    if check:
        return {a: input_dict[a] for a in attributes}
    else:
        return {a: input_dict[a] for a in input_dict.viewkeys() & attributes}
```

That way the user can decide for him/herself if he or she wants an error to be thrown if an attribute isn't in the dictionary. That's the purpose of exceptions -- to allow the user of your code to decide what should occur if an exceptional-but-not-unforeseen circumstance arises.

So I, as a user of this function, might write:

```
try: 
    get_input_data(input_dict, attributes, check=True)
except KeyError:
    # do what makes sense
```

if I want error checking to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use endless

```
except SomeException:
```

You might want to use

```
except Exc1, Exc2, ExcN as SomeValue:
```

or just

```
except Exception as exc:
```